# Weird VLOOKUP issue in a macro heavy worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vlookup

I have quite a weird issue with a workbook I built that is very macro dependent. It centers around a simple `VLOOKUP()`.

Currently my macro creates a line item on one sheet (Sheet A), then copies said line item to another sheet (Sheet B). After that line item is copied, I use a `VLOOKUP()` function in Sheet B to look up the date and time of the line item back in Sheet A to confirm that it is still in the workbook.

Normally this whole scenario works fine. The `VLOOKUP()` clearly can find the unique ID in Sheet B and trace it back to Sheet A.

The issue I'm having is that if anyone enters the cell (using <kbd>F2</kbd>, double-clicking the cell, etc) that contains the Date and Time in Sheet B, the `VLOOKUP()` function errors out. This is resolved by hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> in the Date and Time cell in Sheet A.

This is causing a litany of problems because I have a macro that deletes line items if they error out, so this temporary error is throwing everything off.

I've tried matching formats and what not but it seems to be a pretty unique and weird issue.

Has anyone encountered this previously? Can you share any fixes?

---

Sheet A (note that the Date & Time booked is a unique ID)

[image]

Sheet B

[image]

The formula in `A3` is

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C3, 'Sheet A'!$A:$A,1,0),"Not in Book")
```

This is how Sheet B looks when the formula errors out:

[image]

Comment: If you [edit] the question to include the smallest macro that reproduces the issue we might be able to help, otherwise your question is way too broad.

Comment: "...the Vlookup errors out"- what do you mean? It returns `#N/A` or something, or the formula actually hangs up your Excel file and it freezes?

Comment: @BruceWayne I edited it with pictures, it literally throws that Not in Book error up until  I hit F2 on sheet A in the Date&Time Booked cell.

Comment: @DavidPostill the code is a a combination of a copy .destination syntax as well as manual fills to include certain line items exclusive to Sheet B. This happens post code execution so I've added pictures before I slim down the code section and paste that.

Comment: Do you have macros that are tripped by events on either sheet, such as `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_Select`?

Comment: If `Sheet A` really has a space then you need to use `'` around the sheet name `'Sheet A'!$A:$A`

Comment: @ScottCraner it is not, name was changed

Comment: @PeterT I do not

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by your macro placing a *text* value in the `Date&Time Booked` cells, but setting the number format of the cells to either `General` or a custom date format (deliberately or otherwise).

When you press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the `Date&Time Booked` cell of Sheet B, Excel converts the text datetime to a serial datetime and adjusts the number format to a custom date format (so it still *looks* the same). Your `VLOOKUP()` function is now trying to compare a text datetime with a serial datetime (i.e. a number), so of course they won't match. Repeating the process on the cell in Sheet A converts that value to a serial datetime as well, so the match succeeds once again.

Without seeing your macro and understanding precisely how you subsequently use the booked datetime values, it's hard to make a specific recommendation as to how to fix the problem.

The simplest solution is to set the `NumberFormat` property of the `Date&Time Booked` cells to `@` (Text).

The other solution is to modify the macro so it writes proper serial datetimes to the worksheets.